# filter list of array from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

so here what am trying to do

```
const days = ['monday, april 26, 2021 11:00 pm','tuesday, april 27, 2021 13:00 am','tuesday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am', 'friday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am', 'saturday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am']
    const found = ['monday', 'tuesday']
    const removeFalseDay = days.filter(day => !day.includes("monday"));

      console.log(removeFalseDay);
      console.log(found);
      console.log(days);
```

so it works fine with a single object but when I pass in an array of words It dosent filter anyone knows why is that

```
const days = ['monday, april 26, 2021 11:00 pm','tuesday, april 27, 2021 13:00 am','tuesday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am', 'friday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am', 'saturday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am']
    const found = ['monday', 'tuesday']
    const removeFalseDay = days.filter(day => !day.includes(found));

      console.log(removeFalseDay);
      console.log(found);
      console.log(days);
```

Comment: Try reversing the order:  `found.includes(day)`  Remember it should read like: _array of things_ `includes` _the one thing you want to check for_.

Comment: I get an empty array when I do that

Comment: Edit your question to make it a runnable snippet and demonstrate that.  (Remember that your `day` text is more than just the day, so it's not an exact match.)  (DownloadPizza has just posted an answer that demonstrates a non-exact match using `contains`)

Comment: I guess it cause all contains days at the end thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I got it to work like this

```
 const days = ['monday, april 26, 2021 11:00 pm','tuesday, april 27, 2021 13:00 am','tuesday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am', 'friday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am', 'saturday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am']
const found = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'friday']
const removeFalseDay = days.filter(days =>!found.some(f => days.includes(f)));

console.log(removeFalseDay);
console.log(found);
console.log(days);
```

Thanks to @DownloadPizza

Answer (score 3):

How about

`days.filter(day =>!found.some(f => day.contains(f))`

The some function returns true when the predicate matches for any element

Answer (score 1):

```js
const days = ['monday, april 26, 2021 11:00 pm','tuesday, april 27, 2021 13:00 am','tuesday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am', 'friday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am', 'saturday, april 27, 2021 12:00 am']
const found = /monday|tuesday/
const removeFalseDay = days.filter(day => !found.test(day));

console.log(removeFalseDay);
console.log(found);
console.log(days);
```